# multiple API calls in one componentDidMount using Axios in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, fastapi

Here is my React js code for a single API call for a date range picker. now I want to call multiple API in React with componentDidMount Method is it possible if yes how can do that

````
import React,{ Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/betweendays')
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            posts:response.data
        })
        console.log(response.data)
    })
}
    render() {
        const {posts} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>get call in React js</h1>
                    {
                        posts.map(post => <div key = {post.id}>{post.id} </div>)
                    }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PostList```
````

Comment: What denies you making another call? Do you want to `setState` based on both axios call results?

Comment: What are the additional asynchronous requests? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you want to make multiple calls just use promises or tag on `.then()` methods after one task is done. [Hint : make function async and use promises together ]

Comment: @DrewReese How to pass parameter in react js URL,

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you are asking about now?

Comment: @DrewReese,  How to pass parameter in react js URL if key (Variable) = 04-10-21 . how to pass this in **127.0.0.1:8000/hvals_hash?key=31-08-21** in this URL

Comment: Use a string template like `\`127.0.0.1:8000/hvals_hash?key=${key}\``?

Comment: @DrewReese I tried this before but I got error like **405 (Method Not Allowed)**

Comment: This seems like a new, unrelated question/issue to the current post here, but it sounds like your server doesn't handle whatever method (GET, POST, etc...) that you are using for that API endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.then()` method to create chain of the requests..

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/betweendays')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                posts: response.data
            })
            return response.data; //  returning response
        })
        .then(res => {
             // do another request Note we have the result from the above 
            // getting response returned before 
            console.log(res);
        })
        // Tag on .then here 
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, when I try this method I got all responses in the console but I expect one response at a time how can I do that can you give any suggestions

Comment: @HariprasathLakshmanan One response at a time  ? If you are getting results in array or object then you can use some methods related with them !

Comment: @Hariprasath Lakshmanan I think what you want to do is prevent the default action when form is submitted ? Right .. if yes then what you can do is add onSubmit={myFormHandlerFunction} and when function is called use e.preventDefault() where e is event !  .. what I think is you want to submit the form like normal if yes then after preventing the normal action you can do whatever you see fit .. After your task is completed just use e.target.submit !

Comment: Check this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7y0vksf2/) just to get a rough idea about what I was talking in above ... ( Feel free to ask a doubt if any ).

Comment: I have one more... if I sent a request to API like 31-08-21, now how to store this in fast API parameter. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401904/how-to-pass-react-get-request-in-fastapi-property)

Answer (score 0):

You can add more apis in componentDidMount as u want.

```
componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/betweendays')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                posts:response.data
            })
            console.log(response.data)
        })
    axios.get('link')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                posts:response.data
            })
            console.log(response.data)
        })
    }
```

Comment: As I have used redux , I have called multiple api functions in useEffect Hook. and it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @shaheerawan Hello, how to fetch data after getting data from API

Comment: I did not understand it please explain further.